# Closing if else statement manually in meteor-jade

Tags: meteor, pug

I'm wondering on how to close an if else statement in meteor-jade like for example:

```
if foo
  html elements here
else
  html elements here
```

and what I want to achieve is

```
if foo
  html elements here
else
  html elements here
  html elements also here but it should be outside of the else statement and indented.
```

Answer (score 1):

Since in Jade indentation is interpreted as inclusion you cannot have those elements aligned as such. To put an element outside of the if/else statement, you need to unindent it:

```
if daytime
  yellow html elements
else
  blue html elements
green html elements
```

If you'd like the `green` html elements to be children of either `yellow` or `blue` element, depending on the `daytime` value, you can use a mixin and pass a block to it:

```
mixin color(daytime)
  if daytime
    yellow
      if block
        block
  else
    blue
      if block
        block

+color(daytime)
  green html elements
```

Comment: Can I use mixin in meteor-jade?

Comment: Ah, you should use templates instead - see the [readme](https://github.com/mquandalle/meteor-jade/blob/master/README.md). They look pretty much the same, though. Just replace `mixin color(daytime)` with `template(name="color")` and then name the parameters you pass to it: `+color(daytime=daytime)`.

Comment: Also, `block` keyword is apparently replaced by `content`, though the docs are not clear on this one.

Comment: Ah I see. dont wanna use templates for small snippets of the project. I guess I'll just stay away or rework the logic happening inside the template. Thanks for your help :).

Comment: Actually, in Blaze there isn't much distinction between templates and block helpers, so using templates for such small utilities is perfectly valid.